# Get rtsp streaming URL from Youtube URL using youtube api V3

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I used Gdata API (http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ ) to get rtsp URL of YouTube videos from regular URL (Like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMivT7MJ41M) and is used in mediaplayer to play the video.

Now the Gdata API is nolonger available and it shows error "no longer available."

Anyone please help to get rtsp URL of youtube video using youtube api V3.

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this?